# How to put space between two views which would be same for all devices

Tags: android

I am using RelativeLayout for my fragment and I have aligned my buttons at equal spaces from each other vertically aligned in the center of the fragment using marginTop. I wanted to know about a method so that this spacing would be same for all devices.Thank You in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:alpha="0.6"
    tools:context=".option"
>
<Button
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/shapes"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"/>

<Button
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/color"
    android:background="@drawable/color"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/images1"
    android:background="@drawable/images1"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:background="@drawable/txt"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:background="@drawable/save"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you specify the margin in `dp`?

Comment: Please mention your xml code

Comment: yes I did but does specifying margin in dp makes it same for all devices?

Comment: And why was the question downvoted. At least i did not found any similar questions.

Comment: do you want to show both of these button in center of the page, or what, please specify your question properly or you can also add a simple image, that, what type of view your are trying to create.

Comment: @PramodYadav these buttons are aligned vertically in the center of the fragment at some space I wanted to know how to maintain this same space in all devices. I suggest you go through the question once more.

Comment: What do you mean by "same" distance? Same distance in dp? In pixels? In centimeters?

Comment: @algrid did you read the code. the marginTop separates them by some distance. And that is what i meant by distance which I want to maintain in all devices.

Comment: is answer helpful to you?

Comment: @Aditya and what's your problem? Your code gives you same distance in dp on all devices.

Comment: How are the Buttons **related** to each other and to their? I see no specific attribute to position them in **relation** to each other and to their parent. Or ***are you using a RelativeLayout thinking to a LinearLayout***?

Comment: @algrid I just wanted to ask that given margin each of the buttons above is at a distance of 50dp from each other. Now will it be same in all devices that is will the UI look in the similar fashion as it looks in my device in all other devices

Comment: @PramodYadav where I want to show the buttons is not relevant here I just wanted them to appear as they are appearing on my device. Vertically downwards and at an equal distance from one another.

Comment: I gave answer below, if it not works as your requirement, please let me know, what else you need.

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned you are using `RelativeLayout` as parent, here is sample code, put this code in your `RelativeLayout`.
I created this code, on the basis of question and we discussed in the comments.
You can add all your button in the `LinearLayout` mentioned below, use the given format

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            >
<Button
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:id="@+id/color"
     android:background="@drawable/color"
    />

   <Button
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
     android:id="@+id/images1"
     android:background="@drawable/images1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can make modification as per your requirement.
You can also use this [link](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for scalable dp.